# Font Awesome fonts not loaded on first page load in ios safari

Tags: ios, css, fonts, safari, font-awesome

This problem is driving me up the wall...

I have a website that uses font-awesome.  On a cold start, with a clear cache, font awesome fonts are not rendering in ios Safari (desktop browsers seem fine).  On any subsequent page load, including refresh, or any other page thereafter it works fine.

I tried with a CDN and locally, and I even tried using font-awesome right at the top of the page to ensure it wasn't some other styling problem, eg

```
<body><i class="fa fa-circle"></i> ...
```

Any insight would be very appreciated.

**Edit**

Strange, this issue only seems to happen when I click the shortcut I saved to my homescreen.  If I navigate to the website, even on a cold cache (after closing Safari and deleting cache), it seems to work fine.  Maybe homescreen shortcuts do some weird caching thing?